# save image download url in database

Tags: magento-1.9

we are providing an option for customer to upload an image from frontend [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html)

**1**.Once customer upload image from product view page and click on "Add to cart",

we are saving **custom image** in this path : **media/custom_options/quote** like below :

```
media/custom_options/quote/2/4/image_name1.png
media/custom_options/quote/6/7/image_name2.png
```

in DB we are saving **image path** in **table** : `sales_flat_quote_item_option`& in **column** : `value`

**2**.if customer place an order, we are saving custom image in this path : **media/custom_options/order**

```
media/custom_options/order/2/4/image_name1.png
media/custom_options/order/6/7/image_name2.png
```

in DB we are saving **image path** in **table** : `sales_flat_order_item`& in **column** : `product_options`

Also we are saving random url in same column :

```
s:170:"<a href="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/sales/download/downloadCustomOption/id/7060/key/b0fa267c97fbd0d5ed9e/" 
target="_blank">custom_product_preview.png</a> 300 x 500 px.";
```

we are displaying Custom image in order email with help of above url.

Now, we want to save same url once customer upload `custom image` & click on `Add to cart` in **table** : `sales_flat_quote_item_option`& in **column** : `value` , so that we can send `custom image` in `Abandoned cart email`

**Edit**

we are saving like this [link](http://pastebin.com/6HgCwkHh) in DB, I need add  below in DB.

```
s:170:"<a 

href="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/sales/download/downloadCustomOption/id/7060/

key/b0fa267c97fbd0d5ed9e/" target="_blank">custom_product_preview.png</a> 300 x 

500 px.";
```

**edit3**

we are using below download url code after placing an order, full code : http://pastebin.com/V2zVv0bJ

```
protected function _getOptionHtml($optionValue)
    {
        if ($this->_isCreateOrderRequest())
        {
            return parent::_getOptionHtml($optionValue);
        }

        try {
            $option = $this->getOption();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $option = $this->_getOptionByValue($optionValue);
        }

        $value = $this->_getValueOption($optionValue);

        $isTempData = false;
        $data = array();
        if( Mage::helper('aitcg/options')->checkAitOption( $option ) &&  $option->getData("image_template_id") > 0)
        {

            $model = Mage::getModel('aitcg/image');

            $data = $this->_getImageData($model, $value);
            $data = $this->_getAreaData($option, $model, $data);

            $isTempData = true;

        }
        return $this->_sprintOption($value, $optionValue, $option, $data, $isTempData);
    }

    protected function _sprintOption($value, $optionValue, $option, $data, $isTempData)
        {

            $js = "";
            if($isTempData)
            {
                $sBlockName = $this->_getBlockName();
                $js =  Mage::app()->getLayout()
                    ->createBlock($sBlockName, null, $data)
                    ->setProduct( $option->getProduct() )
                    ->setOption( $option )
                    ->toHtml();

                return $js;
            }
            else
            {
                return $js . sprintf('<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a> %s',
                    $this->_getOptionDownloadUrl($value['url']['route'], $value['url']['params']),
                    Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($value['title']),
                    $this->_getSizes($optionValue)
                );
            }
```

we are using above code to get image download url in DB, but its not saving that url in DB. full file : http://pastebin.com/MLPxi4E0

Comment: As you mention in step 1 it is already get save in `sales_flat_quote_item_option`

Comment: @GopalPatel yes, `image path` are saving in server,  but i want to save `image download url` as [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/sales/download/downloadCustomOption/id/7060/key/b0fa267c97fbd0d5ed9e/). why i need is i want to send an `abandoned cart email` to customer , so that i need to save `image download url` once customer click on `add to cart`.....

Comment: if i save `image download url` , than i can send same url in email, so that customer can see `custom image` in `abandoned cart email` similar to `order confirmation email`.....

Comment: is that path is getting save in `sales_flat_quote_item_option` ??

Comment: @GopalPatel yes , in table `sales_flat_quote_item_option` & in column `value` , image paths are saving.... ` please check complete value : http://pastebin.com/Jmfd4J4P

Comment: @GopalPatel here : http://pastebin.com/qUNqgrEF you can see how `image download url` are saving in `table : sales_flat_order_item` & `column : product_options`

Comment: In both case they are just saving image path and you want image url right?

Comment: @GopalPatel once customer place an order, in DB, both `image path and image download url` will save as in http://pastebin.com/qUNqgrEF , but if customer click on `add to cart`, it will save only `image path` but along with this, i want to save `image download url` also......

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54488/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-gopal-patel).

Comment: Actually problem is we can not able to replicate your problem because for this we have to understand the flow your extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After **Add to cart** you are gettng

```
a:11:
{
    s:4:"type";
    s:9:"image/png";
    s:5:"title";
    s:26:"custom_product_preview.png";
    s:10:"quote_path";s:68:"/media/custom_options/quote/1/7/b0fa267c97fbd0d5ed9e4732d6fdc3da.png";
    s:10:"order_path";s:68:"/media/custom_options/order/1/7/b0fa267c97fbd0d5ed9e4732d6fdc3da.png";
    s:8:"fullpath";s:88:"/var/www/html/sbdev2/media/custom_options/quote/1/7/b0fa267c97fbd0d5ed9e4732d6fdc3da.png";
    s:4:"size";i:78561;
    s:5:"width";i:300;
    s:6:"height";i:500;
    s:10:"secret_key";
    s:20:"b0fa267c97fbd0d5ed9e";
    s:10:"aitcg_data";
    a:2:
    {
        s:11:"template_id";
        s:3:"204";
        s:16:"metadata_version";
        s:3:"1.0";
    }
    s:3:"url"; //Download Url
    a:2:
    {
        s:5:"route";
        s:35:"sales/download/downloadCustomOption"; // module/controller/action
        s:6:"params";
        a:2:
        {
            s:2:"id";
            s:4:"7060";
            s:3:"key";
            s:20:"b0fa267c97fbd0d5ed9e";
        }
    }
}
```

From this **you can generate your Download URL**

Not sure how you print above (May be from quote or any object)

So your download url will be

> http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/(**YOUR_DOMAIN**)sales/download/downloadCustomOption/(**module/controller/action**)id/7060/key/b0fa267c97fbd0d5ed9e(**PARAMETERS**)

Comment: please update an answer with code.....

Comment: How you print that file?? from items option of quote object?? @BabyinMagento

Comment: please check edit3 part in question.... please let me know if that is not you wanted......